# Need suggestion for vim font and font size for window xp for C++ programming

Tags: vim, fonts, windows-xp

Inconsolata looks horrible since there is no anti-aliasing. New courier bold looks ok but I am looking for a better programming font. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font smoothing (Cleartype) is off by default on XP but you can activate it very easily. Here is [one of the many tutorials](http://www.helpwithwindows.com/WindowsXP/tune-041.html) you can find on Google.

Answer (score 3):

[Top 10 Programming Fonts](http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts)

Answer (score 3):

I'm a font stickler, so choosing the right font is really important to my productivity. Right now my fav is Anonymous Pro, and has been for some time. Just make sure you have Clear Type enabled.

Comment: I'm a total font stickler, too :) And Anonymous font is impressive. I would say it looks in VIM and cmd console still a bit less clean than Courier New (Win7,10), but it stands No.2 for sure after Courier. BTW, I find that "top 10 programming fonts" article total rubbish.

Answer (score 2):

Naturally this is a very subjective question. I do have a strong fondness for [the Proggy fonts](http://www.proggyfonts.com/) though. In particular, Proggy Square with a slashed zero. This font allows for many compact lines on the screen, which is never a bad thing.